# Detecting test file path from within jest setup file

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is it possible to tell from within a jest setup file (added with `setupFilesAfterEnv` or `setupFiles`) what the path of the test file that will be run is?

I need different environment variable overrides depending on whether a test is in my integration tests folder or unit tests and would rather not have to add to the beginning of every single test file. I also ideally only want to run a single jest task so that I get a single unified coverage report.

Or is there some other way I can achieve such differential setup?

Comment: Why not configure them as [projects](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig) so they can have separate setup files?

Comment: perfect @jonrsharpe - I did not know about this feature